# Azure WAF custom policy giving an error when saving

Tags: azure

I get the following error when I try to save an updated Azure WAF custom policy.
"Failed to update the WAF policy 'xxxxx'. Error: WebApplicationFirewallPolicy validation failed. 
More information "Match Variable RemoteAddr must be used with Operator(s) IPMatch,GeoMatch"."
[image]

IP address is there then I have deny traffic. Update works but the error comes up and I hit save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if you have more than one and and if any of the rules have any error, you cannot save. If you get an error like this, you need to check all the rules. The other rule had an error and everything worked after I corrected it.